# order by same value in oracle

Tags: java, oracle10g

I need help in ordering search result.

I have one table "Section" as below from which I have to get value and need to populate a dropdown according to the display sequence. But my issue is by executing the order by query directly into the DB I am getting the exact value. But in the dropdown "Sec V" is showing earlier than "Sec IV". Please help me to solve this issue.

```
Name     Display_Sequence
Sec I    1
Sec II   2
Sec III  3
Sec IV   4
Sec V    4
Sec VI   5
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Please give us more details. What kind of drop down are you using? Does it have a sorting mechanism?

Comment: How is your application getting the data? Are you storing the values in a Collection, if so, what type?

Comment: Simple html dropdown in a jsp page populating value from database dynamically. <select><option></option></select>

Comment: Not using any collection. Creating the dropdown inside the while(resultset.next()){} loop

Answer (score 0):

You can order by a column not selected:

```
select name
from section
order by display_sequence
```

Comment: Hi Bohemian, I have tried that....but as my Sec IV and Sec V both have both same display sequence I think this is happening. Then I tried {select name from section order by display_sequence,name}. But by this another issue is coming. Sec IX is coming before Sec V.

Comment: Just wondering - why can't you give each option a unique sequence number, so they *are* ordered correctly. It is usual to see such a column with a duplicated value, which makes it virtually useless